# Google's JS tutorial for Analytics Reporting API v4 fails due to outdated oauth library

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I've set up API access for my (Universal) Analytics project and it works fine from Google's "Demos and Tools" via Request Composer. So then I picked up the simple tutorial HTML file from here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js

But as soon as the page loads, there's an error in the console saying: You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that will soon be deprecated... etc etc.

But the library doesn't seem to have been deprecated yet (this seems to be coming in March 2023).

Anyway, I attempted to keep in pace with the times and use the new library, following the guide here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration#popup-mode_1

That led nowhere (403 errors and other problems, as it seems that is not suited for API access). Eventually, though, I found a guide that shows how to use GIS for accessing an API:

https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis

Using this, I managed to cobble up together a working query. I'll post it as the answer. This is to help others that are affected by the outdated tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Analytics API in the way indicated by this tutorial: https://www.jcchouinard.com/google-api/

You'll want to create credentials for an Internal Web Application, and set "Authorized JavaScript origins" to http://localhost:8080

Save this as .html and serve it on localhost:8080. It should ask you to sign in, you should see the name of your Web Application in the Sign In prompt. And once you press on "Query Reports" you should get a nice JSON back.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="initClient()" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var client;
      var access_token;

      function initClient() {
        client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
          client_id: 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID',
          scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
          callback: (tokenResponse) => {
            access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
          },
        });
      }
      function getToken() {
        client.requestAccessToken();
      }
      function revokeToken() {
        google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(access_token, () => {console.log('access token revoked')});
      }
      function loadCalendar() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
        xhr.send();
      }
    </script>
    

<script>
  // Replace with your view ID.
  var VIEW_ID = 'YOUR-VIEW-ID';

  // Query the API and print the results to the page.
  function queryReports() {
    gapi.client.request({
      path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
      root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        reportRequests: [
          {
            viewId: VIEW_ID,
            dateRanges: [
              {
                startDate: '7daysAgo',
                endDate: 'today'
              }
            ],
            metrics: [
              {
                expression: 'ga:sessions'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
  }

  function displayResults(response) {
    var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;
  }
</script>
    
    <h1>Google Identity Services Authorization Token model</h1>
    <button onclick="getToken();">Get access token</button><br><br>
    <button onclick="queryReports();">Query Reports</button><br><br>
    <button onclick="revokeToken();">Revoke token</button>
    
    <!-- The API response will be printed here. -->
<textarea cols="80" rows="20" id="query-output"></textarea>
    
  </body>
</html>
```